# Can I somehow group insert returnings?

Tags: postgresql, insert

I am trying to insert user and multiple of his user role + return id of created user in single row. I used following query:

```
WITH inserted_user as (
 insert into "user" (username, password, nickname, account_non_expired, 
account_non_locked, credentials_non_expired, enabled)
  values ('username', 'password-hash', 'nickanme', true, true, true, true)
  returning id
)
insert into user_role values
  ((select id
    from inserted_user), 2),
  ((select id
    from inserted_user), 3),
  ((select id
    from inserted_user), 4)
returning user_id;
```

My issue is, that in my result I see 3 rows with the same ID (this is bad for my java application which expects 1 number). I am not sure how to edit this to get my result. I tried to wrap this into another select + many other more or less dumb things, but none of it was working. Could you please help me?

Comment: yes, user_id from user_role table (it is first parameter I insert) or id from user table or id from inserted_user, all of this is exactly the same value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another CTE for the second `INSERT` and `SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM` that CTE. In the new CTE do an `INSERT ... SELECT FROM` the old CTE.

```
WITH inserted_user
AS
(
INSERT INTO "user"
            (username,
             password,
             nickname,
             account_non_expired, 
             account_non_locked,
             credentials_non_expired,
             enabled)
            VALUES ('username',
                    'password-hash',
                    'nickanme',
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    true)
            RETURNING id
),
inserted_user_role
AS
(
INSERT INTO user_role
            SELECT iu.id,
                   gs.n
                   FROM inserted_user iu
                        CROSS JOIN generate_series(2, 4) gs(n)
            RETURNING user_id
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       user_id
       FROM inserted_user_role;
```

Comment: Yes. the final select can also be `SELECT id FROM inserted_user;`